Number of odd-dimensional irreducible representations of $S_n$
In this paper the structure of odd-dimensional irreducible representations of the symmetric group is described, but what is the asymptotic behaviour of the number of such representations? (Or, if it depends on arithmetic properties of $n$, then how?) This has to be studied. One can also ask the same question for Plancherel measure on representations, and for primes other than 2.

Quoting from the first page of the linked paper: "Macdonald [4] has shown that the number of odd partitions of $n$ is $2^{\alpha(n)}$, where, if $n$ has binary expansion $n = a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^2a_2 + 2^3a_3 + \cdots$, with $a_i \in {0, 1}$, then $\alpha(n) = a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3 + \cdots$." So one should be able to extract an answer to your question of asymptotics from that description.

Ah, thank you Sam, that's what I missed looking at this paper

For the number of irreps of S_n whose dimension is relatively prime to some fixed prime $p$, see Enumerative Combinatorics, vol. 2, Exercise 7.15 (due to I. G. Macdonald). For a variant, not well understood, see Supplementary Exercise 32 in the second edition of the reference above.

According to the linked paper, the answer is $2^{\alpha(n)}$
where the base $2$ expansion of $n$ is $n = \sum c_i(n) 2^i$ (with $c_i(n) \in \{0,1 \}$) and $\alpha(n) = \sum (i+1) c_i(n)$. Thanks to Sam Hopkins for pointing this out.
It immediately follows that, if $2^k \leq n \leq 2^{k+1}-1$, then $(k+1) \leq \alpha(n) \leq 1+2+\dotsb + (k+1) = \binom{k+2}{2}$. Moreover, $\alpha(2^k) = k+1$ and $\alpha(2^{k+1}-1) = \binom{k+2}{2}$.  So $\alpha(n)$ varies between $\approx \log_2(n)$ and $\approx (\log_2 n)^2/2$, and the original quantity varies between $\approx n$ and $\approx 2^{(\log_2 n)^2/2}$.
The sequence $\alpha(n)$ is A029931.
Here is a plot of $(\log_2 n, \alpha(n))$ for $1 \leq n \leq 127$; the upper and lower envelopes, which are linear and quadratic, are visible.

